BIND 9.18.28-1 on Debian 12 permission issue
I'm running BIND on a Debian 12 and I'm having an issue with file/folder permission, i think.
When I include "/home/$my_user/zone/named.conf" I got this error:
/etc/bind/named.conf.local:17: parsing failed: file not found

but file is there, so I think is an issue with permission, I have also apparmor and I have insert into /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named the following lines:
/home/$my_user/zone/** rw,
/home/$my_user/zone/ rw,

but seems it doesn't do the trick, I have add it also in a file called usr.sbin.named in /etc/apparmor.d/local but nothing changes, I have reload apparmor after every changes, but if I add the include above on BIND, it doesn't restart.
Anyone could give me a hint on how to solve this?
Thanks,
Alessandro

By default most Linux distributions ship a ISC Bind versions that uses chroot ; so you can’t access files from /home/ ; place your zone data in the designated default directories and you should be good  (I’m not to familiar with Debian so not too sure if that holds true there )

thanks for your reply @HBruijn but I can't put them there, I need they be in $my_user home folder because I need to let user write this file to make modify and reload BIND, if I put them in /etc/bind/named folder $my_user can't modify them. I have a separated system that manage Italian's censored websites and I need to update them ASAP I have it, I do not let root ssh into our systems

You can use sudo to grant to the typical root permission to reload zone files and include sudo file permissions to allow sudoedit on specific files to certain users - but in my experience allowing people to directly edit zone files would be to avoid that.
It’s too easy to make typo’s, to omit updating the serial etc etc.  IMHO it’s much better to have a web form that performs syntax checking and more

@HBruijn it will not be a "real people" that do modify, it will be performed automagically by system, I'll think about sudo because I do not have it yet on our systems.

You don't even need sudo, you can configure ACL to allow the editing of the files and polkit to allow the user to reload the bind service.

Solved settings /home/$my_user/zone and /home/$my_user to 755 and chown $my:user:bind /home/$my_user/zone /home/$my_user
Now BIND reload with list loaded from there.

@GeraldSchneider I have not use sudo (personally I do not like to have it enable on server)
